# Code communication with software installed in PC

Tags: python, serial-communication

I want to communicate with a software installed in my PC: Optris PI 640 and python code. Do I have to use a virtual com port for serial communication? Or, can I communicate without it too?

Comment: How can this be answered? You want to communicate _what_ to _what_ software? Please remember that we're not familiar with your problem, we need something to go off.

Comment: Fast google suggest its thermal camera with USB connection to PC, with possibility of handling by I2C. Without documentation how the data is even sent from camera there is no way to help you with your problem.

Comment: Optris PI 640 is an IR camera, from which I am reading the temperature values via pyserial commands. But since the camera software and the code trying to extract information are in the same laptop, I felt creation of virtual com ports is a little unnecessary. So, I just wanted to know if there’s any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's look that the optris PI 640 is a usb camera, so maybe you can use openCV, here is a little example of capture video from a usb camera:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('camara',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print("fin")
```

you must to have installed openCV and numpy... also can you specify which OS (windows, linux,etc) are you using

Comment: Perfect. This helps a lot! I am using windows.